# Python: Issues with package

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I have created a package called application by using PyCharm.
Below you can see its structure and also that calling a function from a script in a different folder works fine from my Desktop:

[image: My PyCharm Package]

However, when I copy the entire folder content to my Raspberry Pi and try to execute the same script I get an error message:

```
sudo python function2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "function2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from application.sub_1 import function1
ImportError: No module named application.sub_1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have seen a similar problem, where the module application is not found because the program was launched from a sub-folder.  Try adding a python file in folder application, which imports sub_2 and calls function2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm must be managing your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) for you. Try:

`sudo env PYTHONPATH=<substitute path to smart_house dir here> python function2.py`

Note, to avoid other nastiness that crops up when running modules like that, you probably should look into using:

`sudo env PYTHONPATH=<substitute path to smart_house dir here> python -m application.sub_2.function2`

Comment: Hi David. It does work like this, however is there a permanent solution on how to get this fixed instead of having to add it in every call? Thanks!

Comment: You can set it in root's .bashrc.